# Indeterminant in Summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, indeterminate-forms

I have the following summation:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-e^x)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-1)^je^{jx}$$
Then $$e^{jx}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty j^i\frac{x^i}{i!}$$
So, 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-1)^j\sum_{i=0}^\infty j^i\frac{x^i}{i!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{k}{j}(-1)^j j^i\frac{x^i}{i!}$$
However, when I run the program, my first term with have $j^i=0^0$  I don't feel like any of the math is wrong above, so what is happening?

Comment: What values of $x$ are you using? If $-1<1-e^x<1$ then you've got a geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k = 1/(1-r)$

Comment: I was more interested in finding coefficients. The work I'm doing is on formal power series and I'm trying to extract a coefficient.  But in my attempt to obtain an explicit formula for the coefficients, I get this.

Comment: Got it. In the power series expansion for $e^x$ the $i=0$ term is always 1. You can finesse the indeterminate form by representing $e^x$ as $e^x=1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\cdots)$

Comment: the problem arose in my mathematica formula.  That is why.  I will try and amend my calculation and formula to see if that removes the "indeterminant" error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, $0^0=1$ for it is what happens for $n=0$ term when $x=0$ in $e^x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$.

Comment: THat is what I thought was happening.  I'm doing calculations in mathematica and mathematica tells me it is indeterminant.  therefore I can't move on.

Comment: Again, that is what I thought.  I suppose then my question is best asked in the mathematica.stackexchange forum.  thanks